# Как циклом заменить похожие строки кода с разными типами, используя цикл в цикле?

Tags: python, pandas, циклы

Нужно заменить циклом повторяющиеся строки, в которых меняются только года, но как это сделать, если во втором случае нельзя использовать переменную для поиска по датафрейму?
Если это возможно, как построить цикл в цикле, который будет менять не года, а наименование показателя (GDP/C, IR и тд)?

```
m[i] = [y.corr() for i, y in enumerate(Developing_years)]
graph_GDPC1 = (m1.at['2015 GDP', '2015 GDP/C'])
graph_GDPC2 = (m2.at['2016 GDP', '2016 GDP/C'])
graph_GDPC3 = (m3.at['2017 GDP', '2017 GDP/C'])
graph_GDPC4 = (m4.at['2018 GDP', '2018 GDP/C'])
graph_GDPC5 = (m5.at['2019 GDP', '2019 GDP/C'])
graph_GDPC6 = (m6.at['2020 GDP', '2020 GDP/C'])
Graph1 = [graph_GDPC1,graph_GDPC2,graph_GDPC3,graph_GDPC4,graph_GDPC5,graph_GDPC6]

graph_IR1 = (m1.at['2015 GDP', '2015 IR'])
graph_IR2 = (m2.at['2016 GDP', '2016 IR'])
graph_IR3 = (m3.at['2017 GDP', '2017 IR'])
graph_IR4 = (m4.at['2018 GDP', '2018 IR'])
graph_IR5 = (m5.at['2019 GDP', '2019 IR'])
graph_IR6 = (m6.at['2020 GDP', '2020 IR'])
Graph2 = [graph_IR1,graph_IR2,graph_IR3,graph_IR4,graph_IR5,graph_IR6]

graph_DBT1 = (m1.at['2015 GDP', '2015 Debt'])
graph_DBT2 = (m2.at['2016 GDP', '2016 Debt'])
graph_DBT3 = (m3.at['2017 GDP', '2017 Debt'])
graph_DBT4 = (m4.at['2018 GDP', '2018 Debt'])
graph_DBT5 = (m5.at['2019 GDP', '2019 Debt'])
graph_DBT6 = (m6.at['2020 GDP', '2020 Debt'])
Graph3 = [graph_DBT1,graph_DBT2,graph_DBT3,graph_DBT4,graph_DBT5,graph_DBT6]
```

Comment: Непонятно .. Что за повторяющиеся строки вы имеете ввиду? Почему нельзя использовать переменную для поиска по датафрейму? И почему в конце вопрос не про года, а про показатели? И приведенный фрагмент это код или текст в котором надо заменять?

Comment: Зачем вы создаете такое количество переменных? Почему нельзя использовать переменную для поиска? Опишите свою задачу более широко. Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score -1):

т.е. так нельзя использовать?

```
res = [(m[i - 2015].at[f'{year} GDP', f'{year} GDP/C']) for year in range(2015, 2021)]
```

Comment: при изменении года должно меняется и m[i]

Comment: а... не увидел, понял

Comment: добавил изменение - можете посмотреть

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'at' - выдает такую ошибку, но я поменял m[i - 2015] на m[year - 2015], что логично

Comment: да, действительно надо `m[year - 2015]` и на это ошибка выдается?

Comment: Да, как я понял, это из-за строчки
m[i] = [y.corr() for i, y in enumerate(Developing_years)]